# AutoConfigureTestDatabase is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the alternative since AutoConfigureTestDatabase is deprecated? I am trying to test my database using a memory one. Where can I locate the changelog?

Comment: See the javadoc on the class.

Answer (score 3):

Replace import from:

`org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.AutoConfigureTestDatabase`

to:

`org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase`